# How to correctly mock a gcp client library call in python

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, google-cloud-platform, mocking, google-secret-manager

How do I correctly write a unit test for a function that uses the GCP secret manager client library. I've been reading up on unit testing and mocking but I just can't seem to grasp what's going wrong here. I've never really written unit tests other than very basic ones, or done mocking either. I have the following `get_secret` function in a file `main.py` that returns a string.

```
from google.cloud import secretmanager

def get_secret(project_id,secret_name) -> str:
    """
    Get secret from gcp secrets manager
    """

    client = secretmanager.SecretManagerServiceClient()
    request = {"name": f"projects/{project_id}/secrets/{secret_name}/versions/latest"}

    response = client.access_secret_version(request)
    secret_string = response.payload.data.decode("UTF-8")

    return secret_string
```

I have the following `test_main.py` file where I try to mock the secretmanager.

```
import pytest
from unittest.mock import patch

from main import get_secret

@pytest.fixture()
def secret_string():
    return 'super_secret_token'

@patch("main.secretmanager") # mock secretmanager from main.py
def test_get_secret(secretmanager,secret_string):

    secretmanager.SecretManagerServiceClient().access_secret_version().return_value = secret_string

    secret_string = get_secret('project_id','secret_name')

    assert secret_string == 'super_secret_token'
```

When I run `pytest` it test fails with `AssertionError: assert <MagicMock name='secretmanager.SecretManagerServiceClient().access_secret_version().payload.data.decode()' id='4409262192'> == 'super_secret_token'`

I have an idea why but I'm not entirely sure. I assume it's to do with `access_secret_version()` returning an object of type `google.cloud.secretmanager_v1.types.service.AccessSecretVersionResponse` which has a `payload` object of type `google.cloud.secretmanager_v1.types.SecretPayload` which is a `data` object of type `bytes`

Any help on how to do this correctly would be appreciated.

Comment: Instead of trying to stub the calls to Secret Manager, why not stub the call to `get_secret`?

Comment: I think it's better to create your own class `SecretsManager` that calls GCP. Then use that throughout your code. Since it's pretty small it should be possible to mock it very easily and it will work throughout your codebase

Comment: @Pithikos Seems like a better approach. I'll give it a go the next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@patch("main.secretmanager")` attempts to patch the `secretmanager` which is a module but I need to be patching `secretmanager.SecretManagerServiceClient` which is a class, I had tried this but it was giving me errors due to the incorrect syntax I was using for return_value. It's now working with.

```
@patch("main.secretmanager.SecretManagerServiceClient")
def test_get_secret(self, mock_smc):

  mock_smc.return_value.access_secret_version.return_value.payload.data = b'super_secret_token'
  secret_string = get_secret('project_id', 'secret_name')

  assert secret_string == 'super_secret_token'
```

You could also patch `access_secret_version()` but when running the test it will attempt to authenticate with gcp when `client = secretmanager.SecretManagerServiceClient()` is called and if there are no valid credentials it will fail. It's probably best not to authenticate with external service when running unit tests.

```
from unittest.mock import patch
from main import get_secret

@patch("main.secretmanager.SecretManagerServiceClient.access_secret_version")
def test_get_secret(secretmanager):

    secretmanager.return_value.payload.data = b'super_secret_token'
    secret_string = get_secret('project_id', 'secret_name')

    assert secret_string == 'super_secret_token'
```

Comment: I have a question. What is mock_smc? Can you please paste the fixture here?

Comment: `mock_smc` is the mocked version of the `SecretManagerServiceClient` class we created it with `@patch`. When using the `@patch` decorator you name the mock object as an argument in the decorated function. See the example of two patched classes using the patch decorator [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#quick-guide). Two classes are mocked using `@patch` and passed as arguments to the function, named `MockClass1` and `MockClass2`, they must be named in the order they were passed in, from the bottom up. Hope that makes sense.